# How do I populate multiple @ModelAttribute in a POST method without creating a wrapper class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Suppose I have the following handler

```
public class Foo
{
        private String bar; //setter and getter included
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping( "/test" )
    public String doGetModels(
        @ModelAttribute( "foo1" ) Foo foo1,
        @ModelAttribute( "foo2" ) Foo foo2 )
    {
        // do something
        return "view";
    }
}
```

And I have the following markup

```
<form action="test">
  <input type="text" name="foo1.bar"/>
  <input type="text" name="foo2.bar"/>
  <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

My ModelAttributes don't get populated. I have to remove either one of the ModelAttributes AND change `name="foo1.bar"` to `name="bar"` to make things work. Can somebody tell me how to solve this without creating a wrapper class as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You will need an registered Conveter to convert a String into an Foo.

and then you need to remove the `.bar` from the name attribute.

@See Spring Reference: Chapter 6.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion

---

Other Solution

```
@RequestMapping( "/test" )
public String doGetModels(
    @ModelAttribute( "fooBar1" ) Object fooBar1,
    @ModelAttribute( "fooBar2" ) Object fooBar2 )
{
    // do something
    return "view";
}


<form action="test">
  <input type="text" name="fooBar1"/>
  <input type="text" name="fooBar2"/>
  <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

---

What you tried is simply not possible. Reason:

```
public String doGetModels(
    @ModelAttribute( "foo1" ) Foo foo1, ...)
```

Is just a shortcut for

```
public String doGetModels(ModelMap model, ...)
    Foo foo1 = (Foo) mode.get("foo1");
```

But The ModelMap (if it is populated) from the request have no knowelge about the structure of `Foo`. For that Map there exists only a bunch of values - some with a dot in its name and the same prefix befor the name, but that does not mean they form a single object item.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. If the Foo contains 5 different fields and the form must create two instances of Foo, is it possible to do it without wrapping the two Foo instances inside a single object? Think of a form when someone must enter the name, firstname, date of birth of his father and of his mother, both being of class Parent.

Comment: Why do I need a converter? "bar" is a String type. The "bar" property of the "Foo" class is what I need to get populated. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Because you can not populate complex objects this way.

Comment: @Ralh, yes you can if you're using a wrapper class. You can populate the bar properties directly. The problem is why it doesn't work if there are more than one ModelAttribute.

Comment: @Raph say the bar property is not a String but another class that has String prop as its property. If we use a single ModelAttribute, then <input name="bar.prop"/> will work. But in this case, we have two ModelAttributes so I have to qualify it with something like <input name="foo1.bar.prop"/> but that won't work.

Comment: con't. If we insist on using <input name="bar.prop"/> then both foo1 and foo2 will have the same bar.prop values and we don't want that. Therefore we need a qualifier, not a converter. But I'm not sure if Spring supports this.

Comment: Yes, that would be the last resort. But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use a wrapper. Why I need that is quite a long story. We're migrating Struts 2 to Spring MVC. We're trying to minimize refactoring while doing the migration. Introducing a wrapper would create dependencies on struts actions.